# Mosaic Landsat Scenes for NDVI Generation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat, ndvi, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I would Like to generate an NDVI map for my study region, which is positioned between three Landsat scenes.

Which method suits:

1) compute NDVI for each Landsat scenes and then mosaic or

2) Mosaic Red and NIR band separately and then performed NDVI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to mosaic the image first and then calculate its NDVI. Sometimes image edges have distortion or No-data and it may effect your result if you generate NDVI first and then mosaic it. Also, the values may differ if the NDVI is generated separately. If you are using ArcMap, best way is to mosaic the images from Image Analysis Window, define your Red and Infra Red Band from Image Analysis window's Image Analysis Options and generate the NDVI of single mosaiced image.

[image]